# Show that there exists a holomorphic function $\Gamma$ that agrees with a curve $\gamma$

Tags: complex-analysis

This problem was on an old qualifying exam and I was looking for ideas on how to get started:

> Let $\epsilon>0$, $I= (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\gamma: I \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a curve which is one to one and given by the power series:
>   $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_{n}(t-t_{0})^{n}$$
>   that converges in all of $I$
>   Show that there exists a holomorphic function $\Gamma: B(0, \epsilon) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that agrees with $\gamma$ for $t \in B(0, \epsilon) \cap I$

The naive thing to do is to define $\Gamma$ to be $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_{n}(z)^{n}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytic continuation guarantees that if we have two holomorphic functions that agree upon a sequence of points that converge to a limit point, then the functions are actually the same function.

In this case we can literally "reuse" the old function, except use a complex variable in its place:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_{n}(t-t_{0})^{n} \Rightarrow \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_{n}(z-t_{0})^{n}$$

This function agrees with the original function for all values $z \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, as well as defines a new holomorphic function in the ball $B(0,\epsilon)$ and thus adequately extends $\gamma$ to $\mathbb{C}$.